# ARKit – How to move object to specified destination?

Tags: swift, mapkit, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I have been building the AR Navigation using MapKit and ARKit. The idea is it is only specific for one area which is my university, the user can choose the building name from table view and it shows the simple direction in mapView, according to that direction user can choose the ar mode to navigate with guide object like hotstepper app (which ar wayfinding app).

I have everything set up till getting the object by detecting the plane but I don't know how to move that object from one place to another. I have instructions from route in mapKit direction request. If there is any way to move from one place to another please help me,

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: GPS accuracy for the latest models of iPhone is approximately 5 meters under ideal conditions. But in reality it can be in a radius of 20 meters. Are you satisfied with that?

Comment: I am not working with GPS when user chose to follow the object in ARScene. so i just need to move some meters straight and turn left and go again and so forth. What i am not able to do that is to move object inside the arscene

Comment: Ок, what do you mean saying `move object` (using button, gesture, animation, etc...) ? And post your code, please!

Comment: For example, I have detected plane from camera, and when detection done one object appears on that detected plane, so, when you press UIButton, the object needs to move 50 meters straight, the object has its own walking animation, the thing is i cannot override that walking animation method.

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: I dont understand why you need the code,? it is pretty long and which part of the code you want to see? It is totally big project and many files and classes, and i did not know what part to show ,

Comment: The part where you "move object to specified destination." https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Here's how your question must look like: Example – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078633/programmatically-customizing-modelcomponent-generated-by-reality-composer